# Linux, boot into terminal mode

Tags: linux, boot, fedora-17

I have install catalyst for ATI in fedora 17, I'm stuck on a black screen when the system is booting, how can i force the system to boot in command line so that i can remove the catalyst packages??

Comment: 1)  Which bootloader do you use? LILO? GRUB? GRUB2? Depending on the bootloader there is an option to add 'single' to the boot parameters, or even to specify the initial boot process.   2) Which you might not even need. Can you switch consoles via Control-ALT-F1 when you are at the black screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the system boots, it should offer to edit the kernel line. Add "single" as a separate word at the end. That way you boot the system into single user mode, a maintenance mode in which only root can use it. Then you can remove the packages.

In any case, I doubt the "just black screen" is due to any packages you have installed, it could be a lot of different things.